# Compiling for both x86 and x64

Tags: windows, delphi, 32bit-64bit, delphi-xe2

Is it possible to set up the compiler in such a way so it compiles the executable/DLL for both x86 and x64? I mean, one file suitable for both platforms.

I only know of a way to choose the platforms separately, but I want both.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

x86 executable is fully supported on x64 host. E.g. any EXE you compile in 32-bit mode will run without any problems on 32-bit **and** 64-bit host. If you don't know why you need 64-bit executable, you probably don't, so 32-bit executable alone will suffice.

However, with DLLs it is a different matter. The DLL's architecture (32-bit or 64-bit) **must** match the executable where the DLL is going to be used. E.g. if you're writing an Explorer extension for x64 Windows, explorer.exe is going to be 64-bit, so your DLL must also be 64-bit, otherwise it cannot be loaded.

There is no way to combine two different architectures into one DLL or EXE on Windows. So you're going to need two DLLs if you need to support both 32-bit and 64-bit hosts.

Comment: As for combining 32-bit and 64-bit into one executable you could do it with a 32-bit self-extractor that would detect the platform and extract/run the correct EXE for the current platform.  However, this wouldn't have any real benefit over two executables.

Comment: @haimg: a 32-bit EXE can run on a 64-bit Windows system only if the WOW64 component is installed.  In early 64-bit Windows versions, WOW64 was a required component, but starting in Windows Server 2008 R2, WOW64 is now optional so it may or may not be installed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB: Valid point. However, did you ever see an actual production system with WOW64 uninstalled? I cannot imagine that outside the realm of embedded systems...

Comment: @haimg It ought to be common in server land where typically machines run with very little software installed

Comment: Still at some point the 32 bit support will be phased out and then your app will break better to do a recompile now and prevent the heartache later.

Comment: @jerry the extractor itself will be either 32 or 64 bit so that does not solve anything it just replaces one problem with another

Comment: Unfortunately it is no longer true that x86 is supported on any x64 host.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371790%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: It will be a cold day in hell before 32-bit support is phased out of the average server ;-) I wouldn't waste any time coverting to a 64-bit executable for this reason. Do it because there is a need, or you are starting from scratch, not because you are worried about your application not running on a server.